# Internet Explorer not recognizing htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following rule in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to redirect requests to the www version of my site. It doesn't work when I tried on Internet Explorer 6...haven't tried on other versions of i.e. It works for chrome and firefox.

Any ideas why this could happen and how to solve? Thanks much

Comment: IE should not recognise .htaccess rules, Apache should. Maybe IE6 does not know how to do `Location:` redirects. What did you get? A blank page?

Comment: First I see a flash in the location bar: http ://example.com, then it just goes to google search result page with example.com as the query

Comment: You may also want to turn on the [mod_rewrite log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog) to get an idea of what `mod_rewrite` is doing.

Comment: Ok...good idea Red

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't set up any rewriteLog

Comment: Is there any way to see the headers no IE6 and see what mess is it doing? No wonder people just don't support it anymore! :)

Comment: Are you actually typing a space in there between the p and the colon: "http ://example.com"?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a DNS problem, newer browsers automatically try `www.example.com` if `example.com` fails, but IE immediately redirects to the search engine.

You need to set an A record for `www.`, pointing to your servers IP address.